# 3 identical Basins A,B,C filled with water.what fraction of C is filled with water when it is 2.8kg

Tags: fractions, slope

**3 identical basins, A, B, C were filled with water. Basin A had a mass of 3.1kg when it was half full.
Basin B had a mass of 2.2kg when it was 1/5 full. What fraction of basin C was filled with water when it hsd a mass of 2.8kg**

I didn't understand many key concept.

Like ,

1.if it's half full and weighs 3.1 kg doesn't it means when it's full totally it should weighs 3.1 * 2 = 6.2

2.Identical basins, does this mean A, B,C = A then why they bother to write that down?

3.If these basins are not symmetric in every direction then why did it says one of them was half filled.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the basin, a physical object, weighs zero when it is empty?

Comment: Just don't know about it.Just found the question as it is you are seeing right now.